# ROR - Routing rules not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am new to ROR and I am trying to added a new method to my controller but I am not able resolve it. Following is the new method in the controller:

```
    def bulkItemsUpload
    respond_to do |format|
      options = { col_sep: ',', converters: :numeric, headers: true }
      array = []
      CSV.foreach(params[:file].path, options) do |row|
        array.push(row.to_hash)
      end
      logger.debug "Parsed items: #{array.inspect}"
      format.html { redirect_to companies_path }
      format.js  { render json: JSON.pretty_generate(array) }
    end
  end
```

Following is the existing route for the controller:

```
resources :projects, except: :show do
    collection do
      get :search
      get :look_for_name
      # post :bulkItemsUpload
    end

    member do
      patch "/archive/:archive", constraints: {archive: /true|false/}, action: :archive, as: :archive
    end
    match "/timesheet", to: "timesheets#show", via: [:get, :post], as: :timesheet
    match "/items", to: "items#show", via: [:get, :post], as: :items
    match "/search_reports", to: "reports#index", via: [:post], as: :search_reports

    resources :reports, except: :destroy
    resource :email_permissions, only: [:new, :create]

    resources :project_workers, only: [:destroy, :update] do      
      resources :worked_hours, only: [:update]
    end
    resources :project_items, only: [:destroy, :update] do
      resources :used_items, only: [:update]
    end
  end
```

I added bulkItemsUpload entry in the route file but still can't resolve it. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: assuming that is your projects controller where the method is, and that you don't have the `#` there. (and you restarted your server after making th change to reload routes?

Comment: what does `rake routes` show? does it include the route?

Comment: also CamelCasing routes is unconventional and may cause you problems (URLs aren't case-sensitive after all), so you should try under_scoring them instead

Answer (score 1):

First. You commented your route. You should remove `#` sign.

Second. In ruby method (action) should have a name like this:

```
def bulk_items_upload
...
end
```

If you start with Rails I would recommend you pin some pages in your browser:

[Ruby style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide)

[Rails style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide)

It will be very helpful for you.